# Flutter Desktop(macOS) TextField - how to disable auto wrap back text

Tags: macos, flutter, desktop

in TextField(package:flutter/material[.]dart), do you know how to disable feature about auto wrap back text without newline-character.

i want to create text-editor like Visual Studio Code.

In the textField of material [.] dart, if the character is too long, it will be automatically broken without a newline character.
I want to scroll horizontally to see the characters that are off the screen when long characters are typed.